# How to make ImageIO read from InputStream :Java

Tags: java, image, file-io, executable-jar, javax.imageio

I have created executable jar file(using Eclipse) , there are a set of image (.png) files that is to be inculded in the jar. So I have added a source folder with all the images inside `/images` folder in the project . Code has to access these file to create BufferedImage using `ImageIO.read(new File(path);`

Earlier,
To get the path I used `ClassName.class.getResource(/image/test.png).toURI();`

On executing jar , it throw error  *URI is not hierarchical*

So now I am using `ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream(/image/test.png);`

But how to make ImageIO read from  Inputstream ?
I tried cast as follows

```
InputStreamReader resourceBuff=ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream(/image/test.png);
ImageIO.read((ImageInputStream) new InputStreamReader(resourceBuff));
```

It throws error *InputStreamReader cannot be cast to ImageInputStream*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`ImageIO.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.InputStream%29) takes `InputStream` as a parameter so there is no meaning of casting it to `ImageInputStream`.

Secondly you can not cast an `InputStreamReader` object to [`ImageInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/stream/ImageInputStream.html) because `ImageInputStream` has nothing to do with `InputStreamReader` which you thought of.

Moreover [`getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) returns `InputStream`. So you can directly do it like this.

```
InputStream resourceBuff = YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream(filepath);
BufferedImage bf = ImageIO.read(resourceBuff);
```

Answer (score 4):

The `ImageIO` class has a utility method to [read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.InputStream)) an `InputStream` and create a `BufferedImage`.

There is also a utility method to [create](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#createImageInputStream(java.lang.Object)) an `ImageInputStream` from an `InputStream`.