# Can't read input file when adding image in word document using java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to create a word document and I want to add image in it. But when I'm doing this I get this error.

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at access_read_and_write.access_connection.start_page_1(access_connection.java:360)
    at access_read_and_write.access_connection.Start(access_connection.java:165)
    at Servlet.shop_visit_report.doGet(shop_visit_report.java:55)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My codes like this

```
public static void start_page_1(String SalesOrder) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException, URISyntaxException
    {
        XWPFHeader header = document.createHeader(HeaderFooterType.FIRST);
        XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy  headerpol = document.createHeaderFooterPolicy();
        XWPFTable headerpictable= header.createTable(0,0);
        headerpictable.removeBorders();
        headerpictable.setTableAlignment(TableRowAlign.CENTER);
        XWPFTableRow row5;
        XWPFTableCell cell5;
        CTDrawing drawing;
        CTAnchor anchor;
        row5=headerpictable.getRow(0);
        cell5=row5.getCell(0);
        headerpictable.setCellMargins(0, 0, 0, 500);
        headerpictable.setTableAlignment(TableRowAlign.LEFT);
        headerpictable.setWidthType(TableWidthType.PCT);
        CTTrPr trPr;
        CTHeight ht;
        CTTblWidth cellwidth;
        CTGroup ctGroup = CTGroup.Factory.newInstance();
        XWPFParagraph paragpic=document.createParagraph();
        paragpic.setSpacingBetween(0);
        paragpic=cell5.getParagraphArray(0);
        XWPFRun r1=paragpic.createRun();
        BufferedImage bimg=ImageIO.read(new File("/images/page1_1.jpg"));
        String file=imgFile.getName();
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(imgFile);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        r1.addPicture(new FileInputStream(file), XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, file, Units.toEMU(200), Units.toEMU(90)); 
        XWPFTable imagetalbe = document.createTable(0,0);
        CTTblLayoutType type1 = imagetalbe.getCTTbl().getTblPr().addNewTblLayout(); 
        type1.setType(STTblLayoutType.FIXED);
        CTTblLayoutType type3 = headerpictable.getCTTbl().getTblPr().addNewTblLayout(); 
        type3.setType(STTblLayoutType.FIXED);
        imagetalbe.setTopBorder(XWPFBorderType.THREE_D_ENGRAVE, 10, 0, "C6DCF0");
        imagetalbe.setBottomBorder(XWPFBorderType.THREE_D_ENGRAVE, 10, 0, "C6DCF0");
        imagetalbe.setLeftBorder(XWPFBorderType.THREE_D_ENGRAVE, 10, 0, "C6DCF0");
        imagetalbe.setRightBorder(XWPFBorderType.THREE_D_ENGRAVE, 10, 0, "C6DCF0");  
        XWPFParagraph parag = document.createParagraph();   
        XWPFTableRow row2;
        XWPFTableCell cell2;
        row2=imagetalbe.getRow(0);
        cell2=row2.getCell(0);
        parag=cell2.addParagraph();            
        parag.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
        parag.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment. AUTO);
        XWPFRun runimagetable = parag.createRun();
        cell2.setColor("FFFFFF");
        cell2.getCTTc().getTcPr().addNewGridSpan();
        cell2.getCTTc().getTcPr().getGridSpan().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf((short)25));
        trPr = row2.getCtRow().addNewTrPr();
        ht = trPr.addNewTrHeight();     
        ht.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(-5000));                               
        try {
            BufferedImage bimg2=ImageIO.read(new File("/images/page1_header.png"));
            String file2=imgFile2.getName();
            //InputStream is2 = access_connection.class.getResourceAsStream(imgFile2);          
            runimagetable.addPicture(new FileInputStream(file2), XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, file2, Units.toEMU(450), Units.toEMU(200));
            parag.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
            parag.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.TOP);
            XWPFParagraph parag2=document.createParagraph(); 
            XWPFRun runn= parag2.createRun();
            runn.setFontFamily("Calibri");
            runn.setFontSize(45);
            runn.setColor("0A719B");
            runn.setShadow(true);      
            parag2.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
            runn.setText("SHOP VISIT REPORT");
            XWPFTable table2=document.createTable(0,0);
            XWPFTable table1=document.createTable(11,4);
            table2.removeBorders();
            table2.setLeftBorder(XWPFBorderType.THIN_THICK_THIN_MEDIUM_GAP, 20, 0, "090A09");
            table2.setRightBorder(XWPFBorderType.THIN_THICK_THIN_MEDIUM_GAP, 20, 0, "090A09");
            table2.setTopBorder(XWPFBorderType.THIN_THICK_THIN_MEDIUM_GAP, 20,0 , "090A09");
            table1.removeInsideHBorder();
            table1.removeInsideVBorder();
            CTTblLayoutType type,type2;
            table1.setTableAlignment(TableRowAlign.CENTER);
            type = table1.getCTTbl().getTblPr().addNewTblLayout();  
            type.setType(STTblLayoutType.FIXED);
            table2.setTableAlignment(TableRowAlign.CENTER);
            type2 = table2.getCTTbl().getTblPr().addNewTblLayout(); 
            type.setType(STTblLayoutType.FIXED);    
            XWPFTableRow row;
            XWPFTableCell cell; 
            parag=document.createParagraph();
            CTTrPr trPr2;
            CTHeight ht2;
            row=table2.getRow(0);
            cell=row.getCell(0);
            parag=cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            XWPFRun run = parag.createRun();
            cell.setColor("BCDFD5");
            cell.getCTTc().getTcPr().addNewGridSpan();
            cell.getCTTc().getTcPr().getGridSpan().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf((short)6));
            trPr2 = row.getCtRow().addNewTrPr();
            ht2 = trPr2.addNewTrHeight();
            ht2.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf((-800)));
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText("ENGINE INFORMATION");
            run.setFontSize(20);
            run.setFontFamily("Calibri");
            run.setBold(true);
            parag.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
            parag.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);  
            row=table1.getRow(0);
            trPr2 = row.getCtRow().addNewTrPr();
            ht2 = trPr2.addNewTrHeight();
            ht2.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf((-300)));
            cell=row.getCell(0);
            cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2500)); 
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            cell.setText(" Customer");
            cell=row.getCell(1);
            cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2500)); 
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":");
            CTSdtRun ctSdtRun = parag.getCTP().addNewSdt();
            CTSdtComboBox ctSdtComboBox = ctSdtRun.addNewSdtPr().addNewComboBox();
            CTSdtListItem ctSdtListItem = ctSdtComboBox.addNewListItem();
            ctSdtListItem.setDisplayText("please select an option");
            ctSdtListItem.setValue("please select an option");
            ctSdtListItem = ctSdtComboBox.addNewListItem();
            ctSdtListItem.setDisplayText("one");
            ctSdtListItem.setValue("one");    
            ctSdtRun.addNewSdtContent().addNewR().addNewT().setStringValue("choose an item.");
            cell=row.getCell(2);
            cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2500)); 
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText("MODEL");
            cell=row.getCell(3);
            cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2000)); 
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":V2527-AQ03");
            row=table1.getRow(1);
            trPr2 = row.getCtRow().addNewTrPr();
            ht2 = trPr2.addNewTrHeight();
            ht2.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf((-300)));
            cell=row.getCell(0);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(" Engine S/N");
            cell=row.getCell(1);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":V12492");
            cell=row.getCell(2);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText("S/O NO");
            cell=row.getCell(3);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":"+ SalesOrder);
            row=table1.getRow(2);
            trPr2 = row.getCtRow().addNewTrPr();
            ht2 = trPr2.addNewTrHeight();
            ht2.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf((-300)));
            cell=row.getCell(0);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(" A/C Reg.");
            cell=row.getCell(1);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":");
            cell=row.getCell(2);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText("A/C Type");
            cell=row.getCell(3);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":A320 Family");
            row=table1.getRow(3);
            trPr2 = row.getCtRow().addNewTrPr();
            ht2 = trPr2.addNewTrHeight();
            ht2.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf((-300)));
            cell=row.getCell(0);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(" TSN");
            cell=row.getCell(1);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":999999");
            cell=row.getCell(2);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText("CSN");
            cell=row.getCell(3);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":999999");
            row=table1.getRow(4);
            trPr2 = row.getCtRow().addNewTrPr();
            ht2 = trPr2.addNewTrHeight();
            ht2.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf((-300)));
            cell=row.getCell(0);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(" TSLSV");
            cell=row.getCell(1);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":999999");
            cell=row.getCell(2);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText("CSLSV");
            cell=row.getCell(3);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":999999");
            row=table1.getRow(6);
            trPr2 = row.getCtRow().addNewTrPr();
            ht2 = trPr2.addNewTrHeight();
            ht2.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf((-300)));
            cell=row.getCell(0);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(" Reason for Removal");
            cell=row.getCell(1);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":Over Inspection Per ESEO");
            row=table1.getRow(7);
            trPr2 = row.getCtRow().addNewTrPr();
            ht2 = trPr2.addNewTrHeight();
            ht2.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf((-300)));
            cell=row.getCell(0);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(" Induction Date");
            cell=row.getCell(1);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":");
            parag.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("DATE \\@ \"yyyy-MM-dd\" \\* MERGEFORMAT");
            row=table1.getRow(9);
            trPr2 = row.getCtRow().addNewTrPr();
            ht2 = trPr2.addNewTrHeight();
            ht2.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf((-300)));
            cell=row.getCell(0);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText( " Prepared By");
            cell=row.getCell(1);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":");
            CTSdtRun ctSdtRun2 = parag.getCTP().addNewSdt();
            CTSdtComboBox ctSdtComboBox2 = ctSdtRun2.addNewSdtPr().addNewComboBox();
            CTSdtListItem ctSdtListItem2 = ctSdtComboBox2.addNewListItem();
            ctSdtListItem2.setDisplayText("choose an item");
            ctSdtListItem2.setValue("choose an item");
            ctSdtListItem2 = ctSdtComboBox2.addNewListItem();
            ctSdtListItem2.setDisplayText("one");
            ctSdtListItem2.setValue("one");    
            ctSdtRun2.addNewSdtContent().addNewR().addNewT().setStringValue("choose an item.");
            cell=row.getCell(2);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText("R.O No.");
            cell=row.getCell(3);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":");
            row=table1.getRow(10);
            cell=row.getCell(0);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(" Prepared Date");
            cell=row.getCell(1);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":");
            parag.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("DATE \\@ \"yyyy-MM-dd\" \\* MERGEFORMAT");
            cell=row.getCell(2);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText("Rev. No.");
            cell=row.getCell(3);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":");
            for(int i =0;i<11;i++){
                row=table1.getRow(i);
                for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
                {cell=row.getCell(j);
                cell.setColor("BCDFD5");
                }
            }

            table1.removeBorders();
            CTTblPr tblpro = table1.getCTTbl().getTblPr();
            CTTblBorders borders = tblpro.addNewTblBorders();
            borders.addNewBottom().setVal(STBorder.THIN_THICK_THIN_MEDIUM_GAP); 
            borders.addNewLeft().setVal(STBorder.THIN_THICK_THIN_MEDIUM_GAP);
            borders.addNewRight().setVal(STBorder.THIN_THICK_THIN_MEDIUM_GAP);
            table1.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getRight().setSz(BigInteger.valueOf(20));
            table1.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getLeft().setSz(BigInteger.valueOf(20));
            table1.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getBottom().setSz(BigInteger.valueOf(20));
            FileOutputStream input = new FileOutputStream(word_saveas_file);
            document.write(input);
            input.close();        
            System.out.println("basarii");
                }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```

I tried to use FileInputStream but it doesn't work. Then I used to BufferedImage but it doesn't work too. My images in my resources folder but I can't read them. Why I can't read images ??

[image: My project folders like this]

Comment: May be the JVM can not find the image file. Are you sure, working directory has the specifed structure?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I tried this before `BufferedImage bimg=ImageIO.read(access_connection.class.getResource("page1_1.jpg"));`

Comment: I has already worked, then you have no read rights to read this file or the system is not able to find the image file. Does your code alo not work if you convert this relative path into canonical path?

Comment: @reporter I have read permissions in my computer but I'm checking the image file is readable using this code `imgFile.canRead()` then it returns me **not readable**.

Comment: @Mustafa: Using `getResourceAsStream` is usually the safer way to read a resource. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/24824509/150978

Comment: @Robert I tried it but it gives me another error like this `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!`

Comment: @Mustafa: That means that the resource does not exists respectively you specified the wrong resource path. From the screenshot I can see that everything inside `WebContent` is not a Java resource because it is located outside of the class path. Therefore you may use the wrong way to access your files or your WAR configuration is not correctly.

Comment: OK, I understand but I don't know how to get path of image in `WebContent` folder. @Robert

Comment: @MustafaBerkanDemir So I was right that the image file is not in your working directory. You haven't tried `ImageIO.read(new File("page1_header.png"))` have you? It seems that `new File("/image/page1_header.png")`is null. When you replace your path by "/resources/image/page1_header.png' does it works? Will be the file object not null if you use my suggest path?
If so, try to get a file object that is not null. Play with relative paths. After that replace your origninal path by new one.